# Help me to align homework points A, B and C in LaTex

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I have this kind of homeworks [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.3140/viikkoharjoitukset/Mat-1_3140_exercise_set_1.pdf) and I want to get things aligned nicely like `"1.2.6 EX. ... a) ... b) .."`, "` -- how? I don't like that LaTex inserts immediately the point 8 and points 8.1/8.2 etc.

[image]

[image]

**Minimal working example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Exercise 1.1.1} 
\section{Exercise 1.3.4}
\subsection{a) The equation for the affine variety}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? This would help a lot in answering you. `:)`

Comment: Without an MWE it is hard to tell. Are you using `\section` for the exercise? If so you can use `\section*{1.2.6 Exercise}` instead and `\subsection*{a) Drawing}`

Comment: @Guido I tried with "*" but it removes the subsection -name from the Table of Contents, I would like to have it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{\section*{#1 Exercise}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1 Exercise}}
\newcommand{\working}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
```

and then use

```
\exercise{1.1.1}
\working{a) Drawing}
...

\exercise{1.1.2}
\working{a) Drawing}
...
```

EDIT  Modified to avoid to type Exercise in the argument.

**Example what it becomes**

> [image]

Comment: Without retyping the word Exercise each time, is it possible to just have `\exercise{1.3.4}`? Instead of `\exercise{1.3.4 Exercise}`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on the following code and its output:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection})}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Theorem XX}
\section{Exercise A}
\section{Exercise B}
    \subsection{Exercise B.1}
    \subsection{Exercise B.2}
\section{Exercise C}
\section{Exercise D}
\section{Exercise E}

\chapter{Theorem YY}
\section{Exercise F}
    \subsection{The equation for the affine variety}
    \subsection{The equation for the affine variety}
\section{Exercise G}
\section{Exercise H}
\end{document}
```

Output after running the code:
[image]

If you still want to try with 1.1.1 Exercise then you need to include \part command in the preamble like "\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}" and use part command in document body!